# Spring Boot RabbitMQ Receiver JUnit test halting before completion

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rabbit

I have a strange situation I don't understand.

I have Spring Boot Application using RabbitMQ. It can send and receive messages successfully when being invoked by a JUnit test.  However, when I try process the received message (i.e. query the database with the received key), it just halts.

**Question**

How can I stop the process from halting?

When I put a debug point, it does stop, and I can see that the `photoEntity` is populated from the database, but then it exits after about a second. I suspect the JUnit process is finishing before the service can finish.

For example, I get the following console output:

```
Received RabbitMQ msg = 3ade07c3-5f45-4aac-8054-0132bc85880b
about to get: photos... 3ade07c3-5f45-4aac-8054-0132bc85880b
got...
Received RabbitMQ msg = 3ade07c3-5f45-4aac-8054-0132bc85880b
about to get: photos... 3ade07c3-5f45-4aac-8054-0132bc85880b
got...
```

**Code**

Receiver

```
@Component
public class RabbitMQReceiver {

    @Autowired
    private PhotoStatusProcessorService photoStatusProcessorService;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queuename}")
    public void receive(UUID in) {
        System.out.println("Received RabbitMQ msg = " + in);
        photoStatusProcessorService.processPhotoForId(in);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Component
public class PhotoStatusProcessorService {

    @Autowired
    private PhotoRepository photoRepository;

    public void processPhotoForId(UUID uuid) {
        System.out.println("about to get: photos... "+uuid);
        PhotoEntity photoEntity = photoRepository.getOne(uuid);
        System.out.println("got...");
        System.out.println("got: "+photoEntity);
        try {
            System.out.println("got: "+photoEntity);
            photoEntity.setStatus(PhotoStatus.processing);
            photoRepository.save(photoEntity);
            System.out.println("saved: "+photoEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            photoEntity.setStatus(PhotoStatus.failed);
            photoRepository.save(photoEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Repository

```
//@Repository
public interface PhotoRepository extends JpaRepository<PhotoEntity, UUID> {

}
```

RabbitMQ Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    ...
    @Profile("receiver")
    @Bean
    public RabbitMQReceiver receiver() {
        return new RabbitMQReceiver();
    }

    @Profile("sender")
    @Bean
    public RabbitMQSender sender() {
        return new RabbitMQSender();
    }
}
```

JUnit - the test sends messages to the queue, then the receiver receives them and tries to process each message, but that is where it halts. The processing tries to update the Repository, but it appears that this is not completing. It is like the test finished before the processing of the received messages can complete.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PhotoProcessorJavaApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles({"sender", "receiver"})
public class PhotoProcessorJavaApplicationTests {

@Test
public void testProcessPhotos() throws Exception {
    List<UUID> uuids = getAllUuids();
    HttpEntity<List<UUID>> entity = new HttpEntity<List<UUID>>(uuids, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            createURLWithPort("/photos/process"),
            HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    System.out.println(response);
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCodeValue());
}
```

Do I need to add something to the JUnit, e.g. another `ActiveProfile` for the Service?

Comment: What does your test do? What is it supposed to test? Post its code.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for the reply. I have updated the question above to contain more info about the JUnit test.

Comment: Your test checks that sending an HTTP request to /photos/process gets a response with a 200 status. Once you got the response and the status has been checked, the test ends and, ultimately, the Spring context that was started for that test is shut down. Having a test that would never end would be quite painful, woudln't it? If that's not what you want, what do you want instead?

Comment: @JBNizet - thanks.  Yes that sounds like what is happening.  I need the test to end once all the processing has completed (i.e. once the table has been updated).  Maybe I need to get the JUnit test to query the database to check the status.  What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But I have the feeling you're using a test to actually execute a real task, rather than checking if your code does what it's supposed to do.